# Elements always returning null to model

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working with Xamarin building an application, currently I am working on a multi-tabbed page. I am testing this on Android.

Everytime I create an element and try view the object in my model it has a value of null.

I have a picker, that is defined as follows:

```
<Picker Margin="10,0,10,0" x:Name="drawingToolsPicker" Title="Select a Drawing Tool" SelectedIndexChanged="drawingToolChanged">
    <Picker.Items>
        <x:String>Polygon</x:String>
        <x:String>Text</x:String>
    </Picker.Items>
</Picker>
```

In my model code I try access this by using the "drawingToolsPicker" object. But it is always returning null, code to access this object is below:

```
 public void drawingToolChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 System.Console.WriteLine((string)drawingToolsPicker.SelectedItem);
        //Always returns null, if I add a null check guard it won't reach this ever.

        if ((string)drawingToolsPicker.SelectedItem == "Polygon")
        {
            paint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke;
            paint.Color = SKColors.Red;
            paint.StrokeWidth = 5;
        }
 }
```

Is there any reason why this is happening?

Comment: Seems hypothetical..Are you writing `drawingToolChanged()` in `ViewModel` or just code behind?

Comment: Been stuck on this for the past 9 hours.. By view model, I’m using the default .cs file where the .cs.xaml is attached.

Comment: I have just checked this code in .xaml.cs file, working fine to me. Control jumping inside `if` block.

Comment: I have added an answer below you can check if that helps you somehow!!

Comment: I have tried that with no luck, would it make any different that I’m using MultiPage. Which means I have many ContentPages under the same layout in my xaml, but only one content page is displayed at one time. The one this occurs on is the second page also.

Comment: Can you update your latest code here? after the change i recommended. You can edit your existing question for that. And No i do not think that must be the reason. Are you using a tabbed page by the way?

Comment: `drawingToolChanged`  is working fine in the page.xaml.cs

Answer (score 0):

My Gut feeling is that the reason it is not working is that you are filling the Data into the picker using the Items property I would suggest you use the ItemsSource method for it(Recommended).

**If you check the [Xamarin Picker documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/):**

> There are two techniques for populating a Picker with data:
>
> Setting the ItemsSource property to the data to be displayed. This is the recommended technique, which was introduced in Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4. For more information, see Setting a Picker's ItemsSource Property.
>
> Adding the data to be displayed to the Items collection. This technique was the original process for populating a Picker with data. For more information, see Adding Data to a Picker's Items Collection.

Then add a List of strings to your Picker something like below:

```
drawingToolsPicker.ItemsSource= new string[] { "Polygon", "Text" };
```